# Vincular Firebase Auth con Database Android

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, autenticación

he buscado sin mucho éxito como puedo vincular los usuarios que creo mediante firebase auth a una base de datos de firebase, ya tengo el modulo de auth funcionando y registrando mis usuarios pero lo hace en la parte del auth y necesito que se almacenen en mi base de datos para poder vincularlo con otras entidades y asignarle mas capos.

Gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 2):

Para vincularlos a una base de datos, cuando hagas un push en tu realtime database por ejemplo, solo tenes que hacer lo siguiente para conseguir el ID unico de ese usuario y hacer un push al database para ese usuario solamente

Primero vamos a declarar el `FirebaseAuth` , obtener el UID y luego mandamos algo a `Firebase Database`

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

adentro del `onCreate` lo inicializamos y guardamos el UID del usuario

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Luego cuando vayamos a poner algo en nuestra base de datos de Firebase lo mandamos bajo el id del usuario

Por ejemplo, si queremos poner un producto debajo de un usuario podemos hacer lo siguiente

Declaramos la implementacion del database en nuestro **Build Gradle (modulo app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Primero vamos a declarar la referencia a la base de de datos donde queremos escribir en Firebase

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

luego en nuestro `onCreate` **LUEGO** de declarar el mAuth, no antes por que sino va a dar null el userID ya que no esta aun la instancia de Auth de Firebase

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //Creamos una referencia al root de la base de datos
String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(userID).child("Productos").setValue("manzana"); //Dentro de nuestra base de datos vamos a crear la referencia donde queremos guardar el producto
```

Esta linea nos va a devolver lo siguiente en nuestra base de datos

```
Usuarios
|________ Ksl290DNjszJpUn30 (El id unico del usuario)
            |_____ Productos  (Los productos de ese usuario)
                     |__ "manzana" (el producto del usuario que ingresamos)
```

Cada instancia de `mAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid()` en distintos dispositivos crea una ID unica para cada usuario dependiendo al proveedor de donde se loguee, por google, por email y password o algun otro proveedor de Firebase Auth. Esta instancia se mantiene igual para las mismas cuentas logueadas y no cambia.

Recorda que para usar FirebaseAuth hay algo muy importante para escribir o leer en la base de datos que son las reglas de Realtime Database o Firestore, estas las configuras en esta pestaña

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existen dos formas, con write y read en `true` no nos importa si hay algun usuario logueado para leer o escribir datos. y con `auth!=null` decimos que solamente usuarios logueados con FirebaseAuth pueden leer o escribir

**Cualquier usuario puede leer o escribir**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
   }
  }
```

**Solo usuarios autenticados pueden leer o escribir nuestra base de datos**

```
  {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth!=null",
        ".write": "auth!=null"
       }
      }
```

Puede que en muchos casos este todo el codigo bien para mandar tus datos pero tus reglas no esten permitiendo que se escbiran o lean de la misma, te recomiendo que chequees cual estas utilizando.

Estos son los medios de autenticacion que puedes habilitar con `FirebaseAuth`

Puedes habilitar el que quieras, en este caso yo use email y password.

Te dejo un video en el que podes entender un poco mas como funciona todo : [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5QyP9CHpX0)

En donde ingreso el pushID puedes poner el UserID que es lo mismo, y de esa forma, se guardarian bajo cada usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]